# PHP Form, collect several input on single input fields

Tags: php

Okay the title might be confusing, as i myself still confused as how to phrase it.

Hi, i am a beginner in PHP, and definitely no experience in js or other languages.

I'm trying to make an input type (datalist), where when the user press enter, or select the options from the list, de input would passed into an array, then displayed as static text next to the original input field, while the original input field would be emptied, allowing user to type/select another option, and when the user chose other option/press enter, the new value would be added to the array. And then when the user click the submit button, the whole array of that field would be then passed as POST.

Well if my explanation still confusing, just imagine those sites where you can submit an articels, and we can type/chose the 'tags' for the articles.

I heard tou have to implement js on this one, can anyone please help explain it to me? I would really appreciate it

Thankyou

Comment: You mean something like the [chosen.js multiple select](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)?

Comment: Hmmm not quite, if i should phrase, well, it would be like in thia very site, oh my shor, why in the oblivion i put so much effort in searching for examples when it is under my nose, it's very site's question section would be best describes it! You see when you ask a question, after writing the question, there is this 'tags' section where you can chose multiple tags (though the one i imagine is the <input type=text list=talos><datalist id=talos> kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of doing that would be to setup a form with the input paired with a button plus `divs` for appending the user's input and then going through the logic below

1. the user inserts a value into the input and clicks a button
2. The button click activates a jquery event where the function obtains the user input
3. It then checks if the value is empty and then appends the value in a `<p>` tag to the display div and an input of type hidden to the hidden div with the name attribute as `name[]`.

Later when you submit the form you can obtain the values using the `names[]` variable which will store them as an array. You can edit this to anyway you want.

For the html

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
<a href="#" id="add_name"><font size="1">Add Name</font></a>
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

And then for the javascript

```
// Add name
$("#add_name").click(function (e) {
    //prevent submit of form
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#name').val();

    //check if input is empty
    if(name){
        $("#display").append("<p>" + name + "</p>");
        $("#hidden").append("<input type='hidden' name='names[]' value='" + name + "'>");
    } else {
        alert("Please insert name before submitting")
    }

    $('#name').val("");
});
```

Let me know if it helps or if i can help you further

Comment: Cool, sorry for the delay, my machine is busted so i can't yet try it for a while, but i will get back to you as soon as my machine fixed

Comment: nm my broken machine, i tried yours in jsfiddle, and whoa, it's work. Thank you fam.

Comment: Alright, glad it worked out for you. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks and goodluck